# List all T2 instance types and cpucredits by instance using python and boto

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to script the ability to list all of my instances that are t2/t3, that don't have unlimited credits, AND how many available CPU credits that they have.

I am struggling to find the best way to do this.  I am stuck with the syntax to find instances that don't have unlimited credits.  Any help would be most appreciated, as I can't figure out what is going on with the FOR statement.  It only returns one result.  Thanks!!

```
instances = ec2.describe_instances(
        Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']},
            {'Name': 'instance-type', 'Values': ['t2.micro','t2.medium']}]
)

for instance in instances['Reservations'][0]['Instances']:
    credits=ec2.describe_instance_credit_specifications(InstanceIds=[instance['InstanceId']])
    print(json.dumps(credits,indent=4,default=myconverter))
```

Comment: `It only returns one result` - how many are you expecting? do you have many t2/t3 that don't have unlimited credits?

Comment: Hi.  Yes, I have dozens of t2 instances, mostly t2.medium.  You would think that my project would be much easier to script (I'm no expert), but man, what a pain s ofar.